# AWS CodeBuild DOWNLOAD_SOURCE error: CLIENT_ERROR: reference delta not found

Tags: git, aws-codebuild

I'm getting this error when trying to start a build on AWS CodeBuild:

> CLIENT_ERROR: reference delta not found for primary source and source version 0b0b4b6ebc477f92c2d51f2ac4ad0fc0ebc46782

Is this error caused by git or AWS CodeBuild itself? How could I remove it?

**Update 1:**

Here is my CloudFormation configuration template:

```
CodeBuildProject:
    Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
    Properties:
      Artifacts:
        Type: NO_ARTIFACTS
      Cache:
        Location: LOCAL
        Modes:
          - LOCAL_CUSTOM_CACHE
        Type: LOCAL
      Environment:
        ComputeType: BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL
        Image: aws/codebuild/standard:1.0
        ImagePullCredentialsType: CODEBUILD
        Type: LINUX_CONTAINER
      LogsConfig:
        CloudWatchLogs:
          Status: ENABLED
          GroupName: !Join ['/', ['', 'aws', 'codebuild', !Sub '${AWS::StackName}CodeBuildProject']]
      Name: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}CodeBuildProject'
      ServiceRole: !GetAtt CodeBuildProjectIAMRole.Arn
      Source:
        BuildSpec: |
          version: 0.2
          phases:
            install:
              commands:
                - npm install -g yarn
                - git config --global credential.helper '!aws codecommit credential-helper $@'
                - git config --global credential.UseHttpPath true
                - yarn
            pre_build:
              commands:
                - git rev-parse HEAD
                - git pull origin master
            build:
              commands:
                - yarn run build
                - yarn run deploy
            post_build:
              commands:
                - echo 'Finished.'
        GitCloneDepth: 0
        Location: !ImportValue CodeCommitRepositoryCloneUrlHttp
        Type: CODECOMMIT
```

Comment: Need detail information. I think your codebuild is not getting artifacts .

Comment: @mahendrarathod thank you for your reply. I've added my CloudFormation template for this CodeBuild Project.

Comment: check now , i think they have fixed it now.