# AWS Code Build throwing error "CLIENT_ERROR: reference delta not found for primary source and source version "

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

I'm working with aws codebuild  and it was working fine , i have just one branch master and build is taking code from that master branch of code-commit repo, but suddenly build is failing with error "CLIENT_ERROR: reference delta not found for primary source and source version ".

This is my buildspec file code

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - python -V
      - node -v
      - npm install serverless -g
      - sls plugin install -n serverless-python-requirements
      - npm install serverless-pseudo-parameters
      - npm install --save-dev serverless-step-functions
 
  build:
    commands:
      - SLS_DEBUG=* sls deploy --stage dev --region us-east-2
```

expected log,
[image: expected log]

logs coming
[image: logs after error occur]

Comment: Same error with me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55838459/aws-codebuild-download-source-error-client-error-reference-delta-not-found

Comment: Are you still running into this error on CodeBuild?

Comment: No, just checked . Working fine now , Can i know what was the problem ?